# How Spring-boot application will know that input is in the form of XML or JSON payload?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When we get input from any other Service/API in our own microservice, how our spring-boot application will know that the input type is either XML type or JSON type payload internally. And. After it is getting the actual kind of payload as input if I want to convert from XML to JSON or vice-versa, how it will work, will it have the same native method as below;

```
   public static String xml= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root><test attribute=\"text1\">XML DATA</test><test attribute=\"text2\">DATA DATA</test></root>";  
   JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xml);   
    String jsonString = json.toString(4);  
    System.out.println(jsonString);
     //Convert from XML to JSON
```

and while converting from XML to JSON,

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);  
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-15\"?>\n<"+root+">" + XML.toString(jsonObject) + "</"+root+">";
```

Or is there any other way to convert?

Simply my query is like, how to know what is the input type and how our application will recognize this?

Comment: Set the HTTP header for the request format.

Comment: Refer HTTP 1.1 Specification, RFC-2626, Content-Type header (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#page-124). Reading the specification sometime actually help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the content type request header as an argument in your controller's class mapping method:

```
public class APIController {
                    
  @GetMapping(
  public String getMethod(@RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader("Content-type") String contentType) {
  }
}
```